# Cannot use caption in Wrap figure

Tags: captions, wrapfigure

I'm getting an error when caption in wrap figure. My codes are:

```
 \documentclass[12pt,MSc,twoside]{muthesis}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\restylefloat{figure}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\begin{document}
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.5\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[scale=0.7]{pictures/amazon_result.png}
  \caption{Amazon categories after a search}
  \label{fig:amazon_result}
\end{wrapfigure}
\end{document}
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
Undefined control sequence \caption{Amazon categories after a search}
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: Please provide a complete code starting from `\documentclass{..}` and ending at `\end{document}` that reproduces the problem. BTW have you loaded `wrapfig` (for `wrapfigure` environment) and `graphicx` (for `scale=0.7`) packages?

Comment: yes, I have in the preamble

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the `wrapfig` documentation:

```
To use float.sty properly, load package float before wrapfig, and declare any new float
types after loading both.
```

Adapted to the given example, one need to move the `\restylefloat` (which does not declare a new float but have similar side-effects) after `\usepackage{wrapfig}`:

```
\documentclass[12pt,MSc,twoside]{muthesis}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}% since I don't have your pictures, I have added the "demo" option here
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\restylefloat{figure}
\begin{document}
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.5\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[scale=0.7]{pictures/amazon_result.png}
  \caption{Amazon categories after a search}
  \label{fig:amazon_result}
\end{wrapfigure}
\end{document}
```